# Reading file and setting to variable

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop, java.util.scanner, readfile

I'm new to programming, so I was wondering if someone could help me. What I'm trying to is make the user input a number, and if the number is in the file, it'll spit something back out, and if it's not in the file, it'll keep asking for a number. I don't know exactly how to do this, but if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you break the problem down into stages. Amit's advice will get you started, but don't try and solve all the problems at once. First of all, figure out and test how to read from a file. Then figure out how to search through that data for a specific number. Then, figure out how to repeatedly ask the user for a number. Make sure you can't break that code by passing things that aren't numbers. And so on...

Answer (score 4):

- First read the file and store it (as a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), or as a big
  [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), the exact type depends on how you actually trying to
  achieve this).

  Reading a file can be done in numerous ways, some of them are using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) or [`File.readAllLines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))
- Now, create a [while loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) - that repeatidly asks the user for a
  number, until the condition that the number is in your data is met.
- Next, you need to process and yield the desired output.

---

**Bonus:**

Try to do each of the bullets in a different method and only combine them in your `main()` - it will help you to learn about basic methods design as well.

Comment: [`Files.readAllLines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) is probably the best choice here.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Was actually about to add it, the actual way really depends on what he reads (for example if the file is basically a space sperated numbers, a Scanner will be best probably)

Comment: If the file is space separated numbers then collecting the file to a `Set` is probably the best approach - that can be done very quickly with the `Stream` API. But who knows that the OP _actually_ wants...